# Lightning record view form suddenly stopped working from past 2 days

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-inputfield, lightning-recordviewform

We have made one LWC in which we are using lighting record view form to display the details of the records. Earlier, it was working fine, but from past two days, whenever we are opening the component, we are getting the below error:

Error during LWC component connect phase: [Unknown public property "name" of element . This is likely a typo on the corresponding attribute "name".]

Please advice .

Comment: I suspect that your org was updated to Spring '22 and there is some problem with your LWC with this version. Consider adding the relevant part(s) of the LWC code - just [edit] the question to do that.